# How do I prevent the error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code works just fine as long as the database returns a result set.  When it returns nothing it breaks and gives me the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Here is my code:

```
DataTable data = GeneralFunctions.GetData( query );
object sumObject;
sumObject = data.Compute( "Sum(Minutes_Spent)", "" );
if ( reportType == 1 )
{
    RepeaterPCBillable.DataSource = data;
    RepeaterPCBillable.DataBind();
    LabelPCBillable.Text = ParseTime( int.Parse( sumObject.ToString() ) ) == null
        ? ParseTime( int.Parse( sumObject.ToString() ) )
        : ""; // ERROR HERE
}
else
{
    RepeaterDTSTBillable.DataSource = data;
    RepeaterDTSTBillable.DataBind();
    LabelDTSTBillable.Text = ParseTime( int.Parse( sumObject.ToString() ) ) == null
        ? ParseTime( int.Parse( sumObject.ToString() ) )
        : "";
}
```

ParseTime:

```
protected string ParseTime ( int TotalMinutes )
{
    int hours = TotalMinutes / 60;
    int minutes = TotalMinutes % 60;

    if ( hours == 0 )
    {
        return String.Format( "{0} minutes", minutes );
    }
    else if ( hours == 1 )
    {
        return String.Format( "{0} hour and {1} minutes", hours, minutes );
    }
    else if ( hours > 1 )
    {
        return String.Format( "{0} hours and {1} minutes", hours, minutes );
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: which lines throws that error? check what is value of sumObject when no data is returned. It could be int.Parse that is causing the problem

Comment: which line produces the error?

Comment: Why not use int.`TryParse` and then pass the value

Comment: I updated the OP with the line that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add the following check:

```
if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: @huMptyduMpty sorry was in the background coding. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
using (DataTable data = GeneralFunctions.GetData(query))
{
    if (data != null && data.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        object sumObject;
        sumObject = data.Compute("Sum(Minutes_Spent)", "");
        if (reportType == 1)
        {
            RepeaterPCBillable.DataSource = data;
            RepeaterPCBillable.DataBind();
            LabelPCBillable.Text = ParseTime(int.Parse(sumObject.ToString())) == null
                ? ParseTime(int.Parse(sumObject.ToString()))
                : "";
        }
        else
        {
            RepeaterDTSTBillable.DataSource = data;
            RepeaterDTSTBillable.DataBind();
            LabelDTSTBillable.Text = ParseTime(int.Parse(sumObject.ToString())) == null
                ? ParseTime(int.Parse(sumObject.ToString()))
                : "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does the exception occur? On what line of this code?

My wild guess is that, with no results, the Compute() function gets an input of an empty string for its first value of Minutes_Spent which it cannot parse into an integer.

The solution would likely be to perform a check for a result set with at least one row, before running the Compute(). If there are zero rows, provide some default value such as zero or "(no results)" to display.